# Create custom "template" for rollup and detail pages

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

After creating a theme for my new OrchardCMS site, I've got two other sets of templates I'd like to create (not sure if template is the right word). Basically I want to say "use this template for all tag & blog archive rollup pages".

I could create a separate layers for each blog month archive and tag and add the HTML widget to the top of the page with the heading info, but that's just not feasible... I'd like to make it more dynamic.

Looking for what would be the best approach here. I'm wondering if a custom module that adds a few widgets. Then I could create two layers: one for blog archives & one for tags. The module could have two widgets, one for the blog archives, one for the tags. They could then dynamically add the stuff to the top of the page.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why would you need one layer for each blog month archive and tag? Also, what's a rollup page?

Comment: Rollup is like a list page... it would show the Summary views that Orchard uses. Trying to figure out the best way to implement this.

Comment: I still don't get why you'd need one layer for each blog month archive and tag.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... I don't. I was just using that as the brute force solution to express what I was trying to achieve. One layer per archive & tag is definitely not what I want.

The more I pick through the codebase, I wonder if placement.info will help. I basically want to take a shape from one section and push it to another section. Right now I'm doing this with jQuery & when the page loads, I'm updating a H1 in the other zone. Not ideal or search engine friendly. Just can't figure out how to move the shape around & then collect it's value in the other zone.

Comment: Prepend the zone name with a slash in placement. For example, `<place MyPartShapeName="/sidebar:1"/>`

Comment: That's it... damn this engine is more impressive every day! Using the shape tracer I can't find one shape I'm looking for (when you're on /tags/[tagname], the shape for the tag name). I'm having a hard time reverse engineering the orchard.tags module to figure out how it lists the shapes (yes I read the docs). Pointers? :)

Comment: /tags/tagname is going to be served by a controller, the HomeController in Orchard.Tags, spcifically its Search action. If you look at its code you'll see that it's creating a list shape to which it's adding the summary shapes for each item.

Comment: Ah... makes sense. So it doesn't appear I can do the same thing with it that I'm doing with the pages or blog posts. For now I've resulted to taking the search.cshtml and creating an alternate that uses jQuery to update the title area.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery for that. There is an API to modify the title: Orchard.UI.PageTitle.PageTitleBuilder

Comment: Are there any samples you could point to that use this? I did a search for that object, both in the Orchard source & online and didn't find much to give me tips on the usage...

Comment: Well, that's a bit confusing to me: there is plenty of usage in the code base, so I'm not sure what kind of sample code you're looking for. The API is also not that complicated. Do you have any specific question about it?

Comment: I'll look again... I thought it was strange too. I'm just looking for usage... like do you just call it the existing Html.AddTitleInTitleArea() do you have to create an instance and pass it into something else.

Comment: An instance of what? They're all extension methods.